# how to get pinned row data in react AG-grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid-react in my react application and pinned a row in table. I want to update the column values in the pinned row. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put pinned rows into your grid, set `pinnedTopRowData` or `pinnedBottomRowData` in the same way as you would set normal data into `rowData`.

After the grid is created, you can update the pinned rows by calling `api.setPinnedTopRowData(rows)` and `setPinnedBottomRowData(rows)`.